# Unidentified identifier in js

Tags: javascript

I do not understand where my error is

```
$('#tableId').find('tr').click( function(){
  var test = ($(this).index());
  var element = document.getElementById("morris-area-chart");
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  if test == '1' {
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'morris-area-chart',
        data: orlando,
        xkey: 'period', //datetime 
        ykeys : ['retweets', 'uniqueTweets', 'exposure'], //tweets
        labels: ['Retweets', 'Unique Tweets', 'Hastag Exposure(00s)' ],
        pointSize: 2,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
        });
    };

});
```

I have tried to print the variable of test using `alert(test)` and it shows that it has a value. So why is this `if test == '1' {` always throwing an error even when it has a value of 1

Comment: `if test == '1'` is a syntax error: should be `if (test == 1)`

Comment: try putting parens around `test == '1'`.. also, best practice to use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: Also note that the outer parens in `var test = ($(this).index());` serve no purpose; that's identical to `var test = $(this).index();` And if you're using jQuery, `document.getElementById` is usually not something you'd reach for, nor `element.parentNode.removeChild()`. It may be worth working through some basic jQuery (and JavaScript) tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code. A javascript if statement should have parens around it.

Change `if test == '1'` to `if (test == '1')`

And really, you should use `if (test === 1)` if you want to only check for the number `1` because in javascript, `1 =='1'` returns true. Since jquery's `index()` method returns an int, you probably shouldn't be checking for equality with string `'1'`. It works for `==` but it's not a good practice.

Thanks to T.J. Crowder for pointing out the confusion from my earlier wording.

Comment: You're correct, which is why I stated that if they "want to only check for the string of '1'" :D

Comment: Oh, I was suggesting using `===` if he really wants to check for a string. I didn't say that he should be checking for a string. I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are coming from a language like *Python*. The correct syntax for an if statement in *JavaScript* is:

```
if(condition) {}
```